# If function is positive and continuous at a point, then it is positive in a neighborhood of the point?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined as
$$
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
x-x^2 & \text{ if } x\in\mathbb Q \\
x+x^2 & \text{ if } x\notin \mathbb Q.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Show that $f'(0)=1$ and yet there is no neighborhood of the point $0$ on which $f$ is  monotonically increasing.

For the first part, using the density of irrationals we have
$$f'(0)=\text{lim}_{x\rightarrow0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\text{lim}_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{x+x^2-0}{x-0}=1.$$ Is it correct?

For the second part, I've read in the book that "if a function is positive and continuous at a point, then it is positive in a neighborhood of the point." So why is this not working here? And how should I prove that there is no neighborhood of the point $0$ on which $f$ is  monotonically increasing?

Comment: Why did you choose to forget about the rationals in your limit computation? For the rest: where is $f$ differentiable (or even continuous)?

Comment: Just because the irrationals are dense in $\mathbb R$, you still have to show that the limit of interest is $1$ when restricted to rationals. The fact that $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ are dense in $\mathbb R$ seems more useful for showing that $f$ is not monotone increasing on any neighborhood of $0 \in \mathbb R$. What you have read (the quote) is true but I am unsure how it is helpful here.

Comment: f is continuous at 0 but not positive at 0.  f' is positive at 0 but not continuous at 0.

Comment: @WilliamElliot why is $f'$ not continuous at $0$? Doesn't it always approach $1$ as well as $f(0)=1$?

Comment: If $x \ne 0$ then $f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}h=\lim \frac {x \pm x^2  \pm 2hx \pm h^2 - x \pm x^2}h = \lim \frac {\{\pm 2x^2,0}}h + \pm 2x$ does not have consistent values depending upon whether $x$ and $x + h$ are both rational, irrational or of different types. So $f'$ doesn't exist anywhere but at $x=1$.  So $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a)$: We can rewrite $f(x) - x =  \left \{ \begin {array} {c} -x^2 & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q}\\ 
x^2 & \text{ if } x \notin \mathbb{Q}. \end{array}\\ 
\right.$. Thus $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \left|\dfrac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} - 1\right|= \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \left|\dfrac{f(x)-x}{x}\right|= \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \left|\dfrac{x^2}{x}\right|= \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} |x| = 0\implies \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} - 1\right) = 0\implies \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = 1\implies f'(0) = 1$.

$b)$: Let $a > 0$ and consider $(-a,a)$ be a neighborhood of $0$. We might consider further that $a < \dfrac{1}{2}, a \in \mathbb{Q}$. Observe that $\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+4a-4a^2}}{2}< a\implies $ if we take an irrational number $b \in \left(\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+4a-4a^2}}{2}, a\right)$ then $b+b^2 > a-a^2\implies f(b) > f(a)$. Next we choose a rational number $d \in (0, b)\implies d < b \implies d-d^2 < b < b+b^2 \implies d-d^2 < b+b^2\implies f(d) < f(b)$. Thus we have: $d < b < a $ and $f(d) < f(b) > f(a)$, proving $f$ is not monotonically increasing.

Comment: any ideas for the second part?

Comment: I dont understand, where did $\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4a-4a^2}}{2}<a$ come from?

Comment: It comes from solving for $b$ the solutions of the inequality: $b^2+b > a-a^2$ and the expression above is solution of $b$ using quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a function can only be differentiable where it is continuous (and not always there, either).

The density of the rationals *and irrationals* in the reals means that this piecewise function will only be continuous (and, therefore, **may** only be differentiable) where the two definitional formulas agree. That is, for $f$ to be continuous, we require that $$x-x^2=x+x^2\\0=2x^2\\0=x^2\\0=x.$$

Now, to prove that $f'(0)$ even exists, we have to show that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-x^2-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x+x^2-f(0)}{x-0},$$ but this is easily seen, since $f(0)=0,$ so that we need only show that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-x^2}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x+x^2}{x},$$ or (equivalently) that $$\lim_{x\to 0}1-x=\lim_{x\to 0}1+x.$$ I leave it to you to show that both limits exist, and that both are equal to $1,$ so that $f'(0)=1.$

On the other hand, given any $x_0\neq 0,$ we can readily show that $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{x-x^2}{x}\neq\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{x+x^2}{x},$$ so that $f'$ is defined only at $x=0.$

What your book leaves out (apparently) is that the neighborhood of the point must be a relative neighborhood of the function's domain. In this case, this means that there must be some (more general) neighborhood (say $U$) of the point $0$ such that, for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f')\cap U,$ we have that $f(x)>0.$ But this is trivially true, regardless of the neighborhood $U$ we choose, since $f'$ is defined only at $x=0,$ so that $\operatorname{dom}(f')\cap U=\{0\},$ whence $f'$ is positive in a relative neighborhood of $x=0,$ as desired.